# Spring Zuul Maps URL to `serviceId`, Not The `route` `path`

Tags: spring, spring-boot, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-netflix

I have a Spring REST service and a Spring Zuul service. They are registered to a Spring-Eureka service.

Here is the Zuul config:

```
zuul:
  routes:
    rest:
      path:/rest/**
      serviceId:service-rest
```

I expected that any calls to `/rest/*` routed to the REST service. However only `/service/rest/*` will be transferred to the REST service.

For example:

```
curl -i http://localhost:5555/rest/hello # response was 404
```

but

```
curl http://localhost:5555/service-rest/hello # response was 200
```

It seems that Spring Zuul maps the URL to the `serviceId`, not to the `path`.

How do I configure Zuul to use `path` but not `serviceID`

Zuul code is:

```
@EnableZuulProxy
@SpringCloudApplication
public class ZuulApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ZuulApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Zuul config:

```
spring.application.name=api-gateway
server.port=5555

zuul:
  routes:
    rest:
      path:/rest/**
      serviceId:service-rest

eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka/
```

The REST service is simple Spring web project. Its config is as following:

```
server.port=8001
spring.application.name=service-rest

eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/
```

Answer (score -1):

By default Zuul will strip the prefix of the URL passed to it, see [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/blob/master/spring-cloud-netflix-zuul/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/netflix/zuul/filters/ZuulProperties.java#L244) for the source code.

So in your case, the `/rest/` part was stripped away from `http://localhost:5555/rest/hello`, becoming `http://localhost:5555/hello`, which results in a 404 Not Found error as Eureka does not know about a service called "hello".

Change your Zuul config to be:

```
zuul:
  routes:
    rest:
      path:/rest/**
      serviceId:service-rest
      stripPrefix: false
```